# How to ? Animate CC HTML5 banner loop stop after 30

Tags: javascript, html, banner, animate-cc

I need quick advice. With Animate CC I made a HTML5 banner for a client. This banner is uploaded to Google AdWords system. The looping animation has to stop after 30 seconds.

How to do it?

Comment: Which format did you use? Can you upload HTML and JS? If so, where's the code?

Comment: It's .html and .js – But i made everything in UI of Animate CC. Do you need me to share a code of .js?

Comment: Hello, anybody...